# Probability of A,B,C's individual occurrences in groups of 2

Tags: probability, statistics

First. If anyone can help me with a title for this to more accurately describe my issue that'd be greatly appreciated. If you have 3 events that occur in groups such as:
AA
AB
AC
BB
BC
CC
(AB is the same as BA), then what is the probability of the groups including A or B or C. It seems that out of the 6 groups, each individual event occurs in half the groups. I know you can't have 3 events with each having a probability of .5 so I'm unsure how to actually analyze this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* have three events having probability of 0.5. There would only be a problem if those events could not overlap.

If the process is: choose one of $\{A,B,C\}$ to be the first element, and choose one of $\{A,B,C\}$ to be another element, then mixed pairs are more likely than duplicates:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&A&B&C\\\hline
A&AA & AB & AC \\
B&BA  & BB & BC \\
C&CA  &  CB   & CC
\end{array}$$

and the probability of, say, the result containing $A$ is $\frac{5}{9}$, because five of the nine entries contain A. The same is true for the result containing $B$, or the result containing $C$. These cases *overlap* (e.g. there's an entry containing $A$ and containing $B$), so these probabilities aren't a problem.

---

But the process might instead be: choose one of the six different possible pairs uniformly at random from this table.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&A&B&C\\\hline
A&AA & AB & AC \\
B&   & BB & BC \\
C&   &    & CC
\end{array}$$

Here are your six events. You can see three of them contain A, three contain B, and three contain C, so the probability of each of those cases is 3/6 = 50%.  The cases *overlap* (e.g. there's one that contains A *and* contains B), so there's no problem with these probability results.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was bugging me for a while. What kind of probability is this? is it more combinatorics? I would love to research it.

Comment: @SavonBrown  From a combinatorial standpoint, there are $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ pairs containing two different elements and $\binom{3}{1} = 3$ pairs containing two identical elements.  Hence, there are six possible outcomes.  Given a particular letter, there are three possible ways of selecting the other member of the pair, so the probability that letter appears in a pair is indeed $\frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$.